# <li> doesn't work. MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bulletedlist

I have a view in which I am trying to display text as bulleted items `(<ul> <li>)` but it doesn't seem work.  I tried  `<ul><li>` without enclosing them in `<div>` still no luck. What is preventing it display the bullets in front of the text.

```
@model UDP.Models.MCVM 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MCReport";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_reportsLayout.cshtml";
}

   <div class="span-24 last" >

         @* code for filling a grid goes here*@

  </div>

              <div class="prepend-1 span-22">
                  <strong> Notes : </strong>  
                 <ul type="circle" >

                     <li> All listings are sorted according to the user defined sort, and may not display in the order used to determine the median values.</li>
                     <li> Time ranges are based on a 360-day year commonly called the 'banking year'.</li>
                     <li> Listings are 'disqualified' from the median value calculations when their Selling, Expiration, or Inactive Date is more than 360 days from the current date.</li>
                     <li> The Sales Price/List Price calculations will be calculated using the original list price.</li>
                 </ul>
               </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadAndInit() {

        $(".dvloading").hide();
        if ($.browser.mozilla) {
            if (location.pathname == "/udp/Reports") {            // This is for local env.
                $("#prntCss").attr("href", "../../../Content/SitePrint_FF.css");
            }
            else {                                                  // This is for DEV/QA/STAGE/PROD env. 
                $("#prntCss").attr("href", "../../Content/SitePrint_FF.css");
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You may have a global style defined in a reset somewhere ul {list-style:none;} and type isn't an attribute of the ul tag.

Comment: You'll need to post your stylesheet. There's no reason why the tags wouldn't be rendered.